# Redirect User to different page when leaving site with back button

Tags: javascript

I want a simple redirect to a location when a user clicks the "Back Button" in the Browser.

The problem is, I only want this when he is leaving the page to a different site where he comes from. So find out bounces from the site to redirect them.

That was my try: But it didn't work :

```
function bounce_redirect() {
   if ('' === window.top.location.hash && '#' !== window.location.href.slice(-1)) {
       location.replace('/faq');
   }
}

window.addEventListener("popstate", bounce_redirect);
```

Does someone have an idea how to get that run? It is a school project and not for a live running page as I know, that is not a good way to hold people.

Comment: Don't mess with the "back" button

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot detect Back button presses, and even it you could this would be incredibly annoying and intrusive behaviour which would make me never visit your site ever again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why not? I also saw some pages getting that running to find out bounces

Comment: I just today was getting a popup when crossing a one pixel boundary just under the location bar. I had luckily not had one of those for a long time. They are SO annoing

Answer (score 0):

as you mention that is not a good way to hold people. and I think isn't any way to do that without any bugs. i mean without ditching way,
but I think you can do it by "addEventListener beforeunload"

and check " window.location.href " is contains what you want or not
if it isn't change it to your URL

something like :

```
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        //  URL before the redirect
 if (!window.location.href .includes(" Your URLS ")) {
//change it 
 }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Redirecting a user to a different page when they press the back button can be achieved using JavaScript. However, it's important to note that this behavior is often considered intrusive and can be disruptive to the user's browsing experience. Users typically expect the back button to navigate within their browsing history, and forcing a redirect can be frustrating.

```
 <script>
    // Add an event listener to the window object for the 'beforeunload' event
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
        // Cancel the default behavior (showing a confirmation dialog)
        e.preventDefault();
        // Redirect the user to the desired page
        window.location.href = 'https://example.com/redirect-page';
    });
</script>
```

Please be aware that many users find forced redirects like this frustrating and it can create a poor user experience. It's generally recommended to use this sparingly and only for specific, well-justified cases, such as when you have a legitimate need to prevent users from going back to a certain page (e.g., to protect data entry or ensure a specific workflow).

Comment: this is not a solution to what OP asked.

Comment: Note that `beforeunload` also fires when you click a link from the page, or type a new URL in the navigation bar etc. It's not *just* the back button.

Comment: Yes but his idea is he want to redirect people on certain page when they leave the page.

Comment: @FeisalAli thanks for the idea. Problem is, i just want to use "Back Button" users. Not all page leaves. Cause that is also when users navigation within my own page.